# Find rows with different titles

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe

```
    Name    Value
0   K       <apple WK1>
            contents
1   Y       <banana WK2>
            contents
2   B       <orange WK1>
            contents
3   Q       <grape WK31>
            contents
4   C       <apple WK12>
            contents
5   A       <apple WK22>
            contents
```

As you can see, the first line of the 'Value' column is titled. Below that are other content.

I would like to get these titles with duplicate values removed.

If you look after the title, other characters like `WK` are mixed, but remove it

I want to get the following result.

```
  Title
0 <apple>
1 <banana>
2 <orange>
3 <grape>
```

It does not matter if the existing data frame is not maintained.

However, I want to get only the title values that do not overlap.

Reproduce:

```
df1 = df(data={'Name' : ['K', 'Y', 'B','Q','C','A'], 'Value' : ['<apple WK1>','<banana WK2>','<orange WK1>','<grape WK31>','<apple WK12>','<apple WK22>']}, columns = ['Name', 'Value'])
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: No matter how I worked, I was asking...

Comment: can you just write me the dataframe formation code

Comment: df1 = df(data={'Name' : ['K', 'Y', 'B','Q','C','A'], 
               'Value' : ['<apple WK1>','<banana WK2>','<orange WK1>','<grape WK31>','<apple WK12>','<apple WK22>']}, 
         columns = ['Name', 'Value'])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `str.split` with `drop_duplicates` to get your intended values

then use `pd.series` with the `to_frame` method to return a new dataframe

```
new_df = pd.Series(
    (df["Value"].str.split("\s", expand=True).drop_duplicates(subset=[0])[0] + ">"),
    name="Value",
).to_frame()


print(new_df)
      Value
0   <apple>
1  <banana>
2  <orange>
3   <grape>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df["Value"].str.extract(r'<([a-z]*)\s+').drop_duplicates()
```

If you want to keep `<` and `>`:

```
(df["Value"].str.extract(r'(<[a-z]*)\s+') + ">").drop_duplicates()
```

**Full example:**

```
# build dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Name' : ['K', 'Y', 'B','Q','C','A'], 'Value' : ['<apple WK1>','<banana WK2>','<orange WK1>','<grape WK31>','<apple WK12>','<apple WK22>']}, columns = ['Name', 'Value']) 

print(df)
#   Name         Value
# 0    K   <apple WK1>
# 1    Y  <banana WK2>
# 2    B  <orange WK1>
# 3    Q  <grape WK31>
# 4    C  <apple WK12>
# 5    A  <apple WK22>

# Only select content
out_1 = df["Value"].str.extract(r'<([a-z]*)\s+').drop_duplicates()
print(out_1)
#         0
# 0   apple
# 1  banana
# 2  orange
# 3   grape

# Select content and "<" - ">"
out_2 = (df["Value"].str.extract(r'(<[a-z]*)\s+') + ">").drop_duplicates()
print(out_2)
#           0
# 0   <apple>
# 1  <banana>
# 2  <orange>
# 3   <grape>
```